How to set up a data profile for APEX 24.1 REST Data Source
I have the following return response in the following format that I'm trying to manually set up in a data profile.
Here is my response

Can't seem to figure out how to map the following:
lastContact
status Main

I was able to map success just fine.
Thanks for any help
And I did try the Advanced option and that got me this.
which looks like it should work.

But when I tested I got this error.


First, I would recommend to let APEX generate the Data Profile for you. When creating the REST Data Source, you can also navigate to the Advanced wizard step (click Advanced on the Authentication wizard step).
There you can upload a response sample (if you cannot connect to the REST API at design time), and let APEX do the job for you. If you need to map JSON attributes on both the "root" level and within the "devices" array, set the Row Selector to a dot ("."), and click Single Row as the response type. APEX should then generate a full data profile for all the JSON attributes.
The good news is that APEX 24.1 supports nested JSON arrays in data profiles. You should get a data profile as follows:
COLUMN               PATH            DATA_TYPE    PARENT_COLUMN
-------------------- --------------- ------------ -------------
SUCCESS              success         VARCHAR2
MESSAGE              message         VARCHAR2
DEVICES              devices         Array
DEVICES_MAC          mac             VARCHAR2     DEVICES
DEVICES_NAME         name            VARCHAR2     DEVICES
:
DEVICES_STATUS_MAIN  status.Main     VARCHAR2     DEVICES
:


I did try the advanced which looked allot better but I got an error related to LASTCONTACT, I did update the intial post.

Hmm .. it looks like when you're testing (how do you actually test?) it tries to work with a LASTCONTACT column - however, in the screen shot of your data profile, the column is named DEVICES_LASTCONTACT. So there is a mismatch here ...
You could try changing the column name in the data profile from DEVICES_LASTCONTACT to just LASTCONTACT - does that help?
